# how to apply master page to pages in asp.net 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am using .net 2008 for developing web application.
So I created a master page and some other pages. I want to apply master page to all other pages but I'm not getting it. Earlier i use .net2005 here there is option when we created a new page in application and check the master page option, but in .net2008 this option is not there so please tell me how to do it. I'm new to .net 2008 .

Please tell me
Thank you

Comment: .net improved a lot ah, I am using .net 4.0 and you using 2008 :O ... 11 questions no answers no vote cast that dosen't help you dude

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually set the masterpage for pages you have already created you can do the following: In the Page directive of your ASPX pages you set the masterpage like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Master1.master" Title="Content Page"%>
```

Your MasterPage defines a few Content areas. You then should reuse those in your page and fill them with the local content.

When adding a new page the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehszf8ax%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) says that when adding a Web Forms page you can select the Select master page check box, and then click Add. Then the Select a Master Page dialog box should appear.

Comment: you code is worth less if you are not use <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="maincontent" runat="Server"> </<asp:Content>

Answer (score 1):

You indicating that in your question

```
"when we created a new page in application and check the master page option"
```

If you are using a `web application` when you wan't to add a page with `masterpage`
you should add the page like this

```
Project -> 
     Add New Item ->
           Web Form Using Master Page (instead of selecting Web Form)
```

Then you will have the option to select the `masterpage`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<%@ Page Title="test" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPageName.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="PageName.aspx.vb" Inherits="PageNameClass" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="maincontent" runat="Server">
    //here you can add you page data start from form tag till end of form tag and remove everything else. 
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I don't see how the AjaxControlToolkit has anything to do with adding a master page?

Comment: yah.. yah i delete that line check